# How to replace a nested select with "group by" with a "having" clause?

Tags: sql, optimization

My SQL is getting somewhat rusty and the only way I have managed to retrieve from a table the *ids* of the newest records (based on a *date* field) of the same *type* is with a nested select, but I suspect that there must be a way to do the same with a `having` clause or something more efficient.

Supposing that the only columns are `ID`, `TYPE` and `DATE`, my current query is:

```
select ID from MY_TABLE,
               (select TYPE as GROUP_TYPE,
                  max(DATE) as MAX_DATE
                from MY_TABLE group by TYPE)
          where TYPE = GROUP_TYPE
            and DATE = MAX_DATE
```

(I'm writing it from my memory, maybe there are some syntax errors, but you get the idea)

Comment: what database engine are you using?, and what version?

Comment: Is that really relevant? I'd prefer to stick to pure standard SQL without proprietary extensions...

Comment: Then why are you using implicit joins?

Comment: @HLGEM aren't they standard? :-|

Comment: @fortran, they are not the current standard. They are a very poor programming technique that was replced with something better in 1992.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd prefer to stick to pure standard SQL without proprietary extensions.

Then there is no "more efficient" way to write this query. Not in standard ANSI-SQL.  The problem is that you are trying to compare an AGGREGATE column (Max-date) against a base column (date) to return another base column (ID).  The HAVING clause cannot handle this type of comparison.

There are ways using ROW_NUMBER (windowing function) or MySQL (group by hack) to do it, but those are not portable across database systems.

Comment: And it will only be 100% accurate if all Type & Date pairs are unique within the table.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you closer depending on your data

```
select ID from MY_TABLE
where (DATE = (select max(DATE) from MY_TABLE as X
               where X.TYPE = MY_TABLE.TYPE)
```

Comment: Because if, for example, the newest element of type A is from yesterday and the newest element of type B is from today, that will only retrieve the element of type B, and I want both.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id, a.type, a.dater
from my_table a inner join
(
select type, max(dater) as dater2
from my_table
group by type
) b
on a.type= b.type and a.dater= b.dater2
```

Comment: congratulations, you switched it from comma-notation to ansi join, without answering the question!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. I think the query I wrote does what you asked.

Comment: Sorry. I see now that you are asking about efficiency.  Unless you are moving millions of records I would doubt a subquery is inefficient enough to worry about, but I will leave that for others to comment on.

Comment: It wasn't all about efficiency, I was thinking that there could be an alternative that was more readable too.